# Is there a way to get/edit the default layout of a Visualforce page?

Tags: autocomplete, salesforce, jquery-autocomplete, visualforce

Can I, using Visualforce, get then edit the default layout of a salesforce/visualforce page?

The final objective is to modify the default layout for Edit and New action to add some kind of autocompletion on certain field from an external API.

I'd like to be able to add my javascript code without the need of totally rewriting the visualforce page.

Comment: If you have the side bar component enabled then you could the javascript in the sidebar using which you can add the autocomplete functionality to the new and edit page. The added advantage being you do not have to come up with any VF page

Comment: Do you have any example of this "trick"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a the below jQuery in the homepage component. Open a anew account page and type something in the shipping country or the billing country field, you will the autocomplete in action. In the below script I have a static array of country, which you can make dynamic by integrating with your external server.

Steps:
1) create a home page component of type HTML area and narrow section and add the below script.
2)Add the home page component to the home page layout.
3)Make sure the option "Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Page"(Setup->app setup->User Interface) is checked.
4) Click on a new account and type in 'In' you will find the autocomplee in action.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Create a new variable j$ just to avoid any conflicts with other libraries which may be using $.*/
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    /*Capture the list of countries in a Array.*/
    var countryArray = ['India', 'USA', 'China','FInland','Norway','Netherlands','England','Ukraine','Russia','Japan','Korea','Burma','Srilanka','Iran','Iceland','Canada','Rome','Australia','Armenia','Albania','Afghanisthan'];
    /*on Document ready*/
    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$("#acc18country, #acc17country").autocomplete({
            source : countryArray
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Hope this "trick" works for you!
P.S: If you're using google chrome browser then this might not work the first time. WHen you load the page, you might see a gray shield in he right side of the address bar, click on it and select "load unsafe javascript". To avid this add the javascript and css files in static resource and then refer them in your script tag.

Edited:
Now to extract data from external API, you should add the below code.

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
var sid = getCookie('sid'); /*get the session ID cookie*/
var server = "https://" + window.location.host + "/services/Soap/u/26.0";
sforce.connection.init(sid, server);/*Initialize the sforce connection*/
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
    url: "https://api.github.com/user/",
    requestHeaders: {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
    onSuccess : function(response) {
                      console.log('The response is ' +JSON.stringify(response));
              },
    onFailure : function(response) {
                      console.log("The request Failed with error: " + response)
});
```

But, before making this request make sure that you add the external api (https://api.github.com) in the remote site settings(setup->administrator-> security controls - > remote site settings)

Comment: Ok, the autocompletion part is working from static data, but obviously I can't access an external API using the ajax tookit (because of the missing session ID and the same origin policy), any clue or another clever trick to do that?

Comment: Thanks! I managed to directly call (without the ajax proxy) my API using jsonp. But I guess it will be very useful when a jsonp implementation is not provided!

Comment: Cool. With JSONP you can only do a GET request but you cant do a POST request if you want to send some data back to your external server.. Could you please change the title of this question something more appropriate like, "implementing autocomplete on a standard page"?